# How to query with results of another query in Hasura graphql?

Tags: graphql, hasura

I have a query which will return the list of users who are seen

```
seen_user(where: {user: {_eq: $user}}) {
   user
 }
```

How do i query the profile's of user who are not seen

```
  userprofile(where: {_not: results of the above query) {
    username
    pictures {
      url
    }
  }
}
```

How to do this in a single query?

Comment: Unless they are in the same table, this is not directly possible. But you can use Postgres functions which does the functionality of the above and you can call that function directly from your client.

Comment: You can also create a view for this.